# PL/SQL duplicate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm executing the following PL/SQL script on sqlplus :

```
 declare
        cursor c is  select sal, empno, ename from emp where ((comm is null and sal>2000) or (comm is not null and (sal+comm)>2000));
              v_sal emp.sal%type;
              v_empno emp.sal%type;
              v_ename emp.ename%type;
             begin
              open c;
              loop
                 fetch c into v_sal,v_empno,v_ename;
                 insert into temp values(v_sal,v_empno,v_ename);
                 exit when(c%notfound);
              end loop;
              close c;
         end;
        /
```

I obtain all the n-uplets I want but the last one is duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `exit` statement before `insert`.